# Ansible Debugger: continue execution when a task fails

Tags: debugging, ansible

I'm aware that the `continue` command will continue running the playbook, however it will stop running tasks on the failed host. Is there any way to continue running tasks on the host that failed?

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_debugger.html

Answer (score 0):

In the task level, if it's likely to be failure, e.g. stop a stopped server, you can indicate "ignore_errors: yes", to tell Ansible it's OK to fail the task and continue, e.g.:

- name: This task could fail, but it doesn't matter, contiue with next task
  shell: "stop_server.sh"
  ignore_errors: yes

While in host level, you already have the configuration to continue

Not sure if that's something you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

A workaround: always [skip a task in check mode](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#skipping-tasks-or-ignoring-errors-in-check-mode) by adding the following field to a task:
`ignore_errors: "{{ ansible_check_mode }}"`